# Fixing an error 9004 without taking the database offline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transaction-log

My database (SQL Server 2008 r2) is running fine but I’m getting the following error in my event log.

```
Error: 9004, Severity: 23, State: 6.
An error occurred while processing the log for database 'MyDB'.  If possible, restore from
backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.
```

Is there any way to fix this without taking the database offline?

If not, what would be the fastest way? Transactional data loss would be accepted.

Comment: What is the state of the error?  Do you have proper backups?  Documents that should be read before continuing: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015753 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/15/632398.aspx

Comment: State: 6
I have read that document. It indicates a CHECKDB which I would try to avoid as ti will keep the database offline for a very long time.

Comment: @Kenny No, DBCC checkdb does not takes database offliine and you can run it on online database. But yes DBCC CHECKDB is highly resourse intensive. Checkdb creates a snapshot of current database and runs recovery on it and then run checkdb on that snapshot this snapshot is *synced* with main database when you make changes in main database so it's advisable to run checkdb during maintenance window or whe load is relatively less. And checkdb does not checks consistency of LOG FILE

Comment: @Shanky "DBCC CHECKDB ([MyDB], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS" results in a "Repair statement not processed. Database needs to be in single user mode." error.

Comment: I was talking about running checkdb to check integirty of database *not repair*. You can run dbcc checkdb(db_name) with no_infomsgs, all errormsgs to first check whether there is any data corruption in database or not. Are you ware that repair_allow_data_loss MIGHT actually delete few data to remove corruption. Its dangerous to use so use on own risk. Yes you need to put database is single user mode to run repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know why, but deleting and recreating the replication on the database caused the error not to reappear.

Comment: Because you moved the reader agent forward past the point of the issue.

Comment: @Sean So do I still have an issue?

Comment: Probably not, when the log wraps back around it'll reformat the header and information in the vlf/log blocks. That should take care of the issue (assuming it's limited to a 9004).

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing much else about your problem, if your database is online and you're not using anything that may be actively using part of the log - such as Mirroring, AGs, Replication, etc, you could attempt removing that part of the log from the sweep by changing to the simple recovery mode (if in bulk or full) and issuing a checkpoint. Then go back to your normal recovery model and either take a full or differential to restart a valid LSN chain.

This may or may not work for you depending on what the actual underlying cause is, but should work for most cases caused by a state of 6.

Please note: I am not advocating that you do anything to compromise your database. If the database is online and functioning, this won't cause any data loss nor would it be destructive other than to your LSN chain which can be bridged.

Comment: It is a transactional replicated database. I removed the replication so I could try your solution and now I don’t get the 9004 error anymore. I will recreate the replication this weekend and see if the error returns.